# I need help placing a 301 redirect in my htaccess file of my new php site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a php website and my current `.htaccess` file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

#Options +FollowSymlinks


RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]


Options -Indexes


</IfModule>
```

Now I want to do a 301 redirect on a URL. From `example.com/folder/old-url-london.htm` to `example.com/new-url-london/`

The problem is everytime I try something I get:

```
www.example.com/new-url-london/?page=folder/old-url-london.htm
```

Now I can't change this line (`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`) as it is essential to the working of the website.

Any ideas?

I tried the following:

```
Redirect 301 /folder/old-url-london.htm example.com/new-url-london/
```

as well as

```
RewriteRule ^folder/old-url-london.htm$ /new-url-london/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are perhaps putting the rule in the wrong place. Or used the `Redirect` directive. And/or are perhaps now seeing a cached response.

You need to use mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` to avoid conflicts with the existing rewrite AND the rule needs to be at the top of the file, *before* the existing rewrite and ideally after the `RewriteEngine` directive.

For example:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^folder/old-url-london\.htm$ /new-url-london/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, since any erroneous 301 (permanent) redirects will have been cached by the browser. Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects for this reason.

Don't forget to backslash-escape literal dots in the regex.

I tidied up a few other bits:

- `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required.
- Combined `Options` at the top and re-enabled `FollowSymLinks` (since it is required by mod_rewrite)
- `RewriteBase` is not required in the directives you've posted.
- Removed spurious spacing.
- `NC` flag not required on the rewrite since the pattern `.*` already matches everything.
- The anchors on the pattern `^(.*)$` are not required since regex is greedy by default.

Comment: Thanks. You are right about the ordering. I needed to put the new RewriteRule before the old code. And I did forget to backslash-escape literal dots!

I will give it ago and let you know what happens.